# How to add side menu on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add side menus to the sub-menus like PRODUCT 1, PRODUCT 2 etc. that appear on the side on hover over them. How do I do that on the following code?

This is the code that I have so far.

**CSS**:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400, 600, 300);
 @charset"UTF-8";

/* Base Styles */
 #cssmenu, #cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li, #cssmenu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu a {
    line-height: 1.3;
}
#cssmenu {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    background: #A3FFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
    background: #A3FFFF;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #565656), color-stop(100%, #323232));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
    border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    background: #47A3FF;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#47A3FF 0%, #47A3FF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #47A3FF), color-stop(100%, #47A3FF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#47A3FF 0%, #47A3FF 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#47A3FF 0%, #47A3FF 100%);
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
    border: 1px solid #47A3FF;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a span {
    border: 1px solid #47A3FF;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a span {
    background: url(images/icon_plus.png) 98% center no-repeat;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has -sub.active > a span {
    background: url(images/icon_minus.png) 98% center no-repeat;
}
/* Sub menu */
 #cssmenu ul ul {
    padding: 5px 12px;
    display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
    padding: 3px 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
    display: block;
    color: #191975;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
    color: cornflowerblue;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**JS**:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
            $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
                checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            }
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            }
            if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'>
            <a href='#'><span>CENTRAL COMPLIANCE</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'><span>PRODUCT 1</span></a></li>
                <hr>
                <li><a href='#'><span>PRODUCT 2</span></a></li>
                <hr>
                <li><a href='#'><span>PRODUCT 3</span></a></li>
                <hr>
                <li><a href='#'><span>PRODUCT 4</span></a></li>
                <hr>
                <li><a href='#'><span>GEPOC</span></a></li>
                <hr>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Global Registration</span></a></li>
                <hr>
                <li><a href='#'><span>MBL</span></a></li>
                <hr>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Account Affirmations</span></a></li>
                <hr>
                <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Outside Affiliations</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'>
            <a href='#'><span>CONTROL ROOM</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'><span>CDS</span></a></li>
                <hr>
                <li><a href='#'><span>UK Registration</span></a></li>
                <hr>
                <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Compliance Portal</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'>
            <a href='#'><span>LARGE HOLDINGS</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>LHO</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'>
            <a href='#'><span>ORCHESTRIA</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Orchestria</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please help me edit this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The css attribute :hover should work well. Begin with a div that has a display of none. Then on hover of product 1, for example, change to display block.

```
.side-menu {
  display:none;
}
.product1:hover > .side-menu {
  display:block;
}
```

It is important to note that this only works if the menu item that is to be hidden and shown is a child of the the item you are hovering over. That shouldn't be an issue for you.

Edit for Clarification:
In your HTML add the ul that will hold your side menu. Assign a class to the ul. This is how you create a nested list. Also add a class to the li product 1 so that we can select it.

```
<li><a href="#" class="product1">Product1</a></li>
  <ul class="side-menu">
    <li>first sub menu item</ul>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Now your css. It will be the same as what I wrote above because I used the same class names. What happens is when the page loads the side menu will be hidden because the display is set to none. When you :hover over the html element with a class of 'product1' it changes the display attribute of the side menu from none to block.

You will still need to position the new menu item appropriately.

Comment: Could you tell me the what to add in html and css separately and clearly for this? I'm still kinda confused.

Comment: You might want to spend some more time learning the fundamentals of HTML and CSS. It will make everything much easier for you. Another option is to look into bootstrap.